# How do I choose the last item in nested div with css?

Tags: css

I need to select the last `div` (only **Subtask3** not task1 and task2) from the nested divs without adding class/id.

```
  <div>
      <div>Subtask1
       <div>Task1</div>
       <div>Task2</div>
       <div>Task3</div>
      </div>
    
      <div>Subtask2
        <div>Task1</div>
        <div>Task2</div>
        <div>Task3</div>
      </div>
    
      <div>Subtask3
        <div>Task1</div>
        <div>Task2</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I tried `div>div:nth-last-of-type(-n+1) { color: green;}` and `div>div:last-child { color: green;}` but it takes last Tasks as well (I need only the last Subtask ... in this case Subtask3) ... it shouldn't be static the third! because Subtasks could be more than 3. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to add class but you can use it :

```
div>div:not(div>div>div):last-child { 
  color: green;
}
div>div>div{
  color:black;
}
```

See JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/24kmd0t8/1/

Comment: Nice solution! I thought that leaving as task as "default" was not necessary. Given that the objective is to select only or block

Comment: I know, but for me it's impossible with only one selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope I have helped you.

```css
div:nth-last-child(-n+1){
  background: red;
} 
div>div>div:nth-child(n)
{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <div>Subtask1
       <div>Task1</div>
       <div>Task2</div>
       <div>Task3</div>
      </div>
    
      <div>Subtask2
        <div>Task1</div>
        <div>Task2</div>
        <div>Task3</div>
      </div>
    
      <div>Subtask3
        <div>Task1</div>
        <div>Task2</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you want to do it with CSS.

Anyway, I can give you a solution with JQUERY

```
 $('div').parent().closest('div').last().addClass("last");
```

```js
  $('div').parent().closest('div').last().addClass("last");
```

```css
.last {
  background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
      <div>Subtask1
       <div>Task1</div>
       <div>Task2</div>
       <div>Task3</div>
      </div>
    
      <div>Subtask2
        <div>Task1</div>
        <div>Task2</div>
        <div>Task3</div>
      </div>
    
      <div>Subtask3
        <div>Task1</div>
        <div>Task2</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think it would be more useful to answer the OP's question with the libraries (or here lack of) they are using. Importing JQuery for this seems very excessive considering this can be done without any additional library in 1 line.